# Export data vertically

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic, scripting

I have data that I want to export to a text file.

```
s = Subsets[{a, b, c}];
r = Table[s[i]] + 1, {i, Length[s]}];
Export["file.TXT", {r, s}, "Table"]
```

> ```
> {}    {1 + a} {1 + b} {1 + c} {1 + a, 1 + b}  {1 + a, 1 + c}  {1 + b, 1 + c}  {1 + a, 1 + b, 1 + c}
> {}    {a} {b} {c} {a, b}  {a, c}  {b, c}  {a, b, c}
> ```

But I need to  Export data vertically.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `Export["file.TXT", Transpose[{r, s}], "Table"]`?

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, you want to add 1 to every element.This can be done by: `Map[# + 1 &, s, {2}]`